# wmic command how to use negative number for search

Tags: windows, command, wmic

In  wmic, '-' is special characters.
how can use negative number for search? 
just like

```
wmic volume where serialnumber=-1874012763
```

because '-' is sepcial character, this command is not work.

how can i assign negative number for search in wmic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SerialNumber value from Win32_Volume class is an unsigned integer (uint32), there's no way to query an unsigned integer value using WMIC since you cannot convert the value, you can only list all values:

```
wmic /namespace:\\root\cimv2 path Win32_Volume get SerialNumber /value
```

As far as I know, you can overcome querying an unsigned integer value by scripting it. For example using VBS quering for an unsigned integer value of '-1435665788' (my systems C drive):

```
Option Explicit
Const SN_VAL=-1435665788
Dim oWMI, oQRY, oItm, sComp, sMsg
sComp = "."
Set oWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate,authenticationLevel=pktPrivacy}!\\" & sComp & "\root\cimv2")
Set oQRY = oWMI.ExecQuery("select * from Win32_Volume") 
For Each oItm In oQRY 
  If oItm.SerialNumber = SN_VAL Then 
    MsgBox "  DriveLetter: " & oItm.DriveLetter & vbCrLf & _
           " SerialNumber: " & oItm.SerialNumber, vbOkOnly, "WMI Results"
  End If
Next 
Set oQRY = Nothing
Set oWMI = Nothing
WScript.Quit(0)
```

The above prompts the drive letter and serial number for the given unsigned integer value. Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that example is correct as according to docs this property is uint32.

Anyway, to escape this behavior I would try to use:

```
wmic volume where (serialnumber=-1874012763)
```

Comment: That's because this query, as I mentioned *is* invalid. Can you show where did you find volume with negative serialnumber? I checked on many hosts and it's always, as documentation states, positive... :)

Comment: I use this command check serailnumber: 
wmic volume get serialnumber,driveletter

Answer (score 0):

Double quote the value;

```
wmic volume where serialnumber="-1874012763" get ...
```